# Rename HTTP header in Apache

Tags: apache

I would like to set the value of the `Authorization` header to be the same as the value of the `CustomAuthorization` header.  Or in other words, rename the header.  According to the docs, it sounds like I should be able to do it like this:

```
RequestHeader set Authorization %{HTTP:CustomAuthorization}
```

But that produces an error:

```
# apachectl configtest
AH00526: Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/01-netbox.conf:
Unrecognized header format %
```

It works if I set it to a static value like this:

```
RequestHeader set Authorization foo
```

I'm using Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)

Comment: have you tried `%{CustomAuthorization}e` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, this works:

```
RequestHeader set Authorization "expr=%{req:CustomAuthorization}"
```